# Add a CONCAT field to hook_views_data in Drupal 6

Tags: views

I'm working with getting a GROUP_CONCAT field into views for my module and I've been using this answer as a guide: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/12364/2735.

I'm almost there, having successfully added the groupby to a new field in _view_query_alter. The problem I'm having is getting that field out into views, so that it's an option in the "Fields" area of the views UI. In the SQL, according to Views, I've correctly got the GROUP BY and the GROUP_CONCAT, where the concat in the SELECT looks something like:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(month_id) AS months
```

However, when I try to get 'months' back out in _views_data, it either (a) adds the table name to 'months' as in:

```
SELECT mytable.field1,
mytable.months ...
```

or (b) does not recognize the field at all in the Views UI.

In _views_data, I try defining the field with:

```
$data['mytable']['months']
```

which produces (a), and with:

```
$data['']['months']
```

which produces (b). I know I'm missing something small here. Can anyone tell me what it is?

----UPDATED to show the code I have so far, added to my .module file -----

```
/*
----the table that my module uses: ----
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `drupal_seasonality_chart` (
  `food_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `month_id` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `is_partial` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `veg_or_fruit` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`food_id`,`month_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
--------
notes:
 - food_id relates to a term_id
 - each food_id can have many month_ids

*/


//this function is adapted from: http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!views!docs!docs.php/function/hook_views_data/6 
function seasonality_chart_views_data() {

    //group
    $data['seasonality_chart']['table']['group'] = t('Seasonality');

//base table
    $data['seasonality_chart']['table']['base'] = array(
    'field' => 'food_id', 
    'title' => t('Seasonality table'), 
    'help' => t("Seasonality content related to food tags."), 
    'weight' => -10,
    );

    //join. The food_id in the module table relates to a term id (tid) in term_data
    $data['seasonality_chart']['table']['join'] = array(
         'term_data' => array(
         'left_table' => 'term_data',
         'left_field' => 'tid', 
         'field' => 'food_id',
         ),
       );

    // Food ID field.
      $data['seasonality_chart']['food_id'] = array(
        'title' => t('Food id'), 
        'help' => t('References a food tag'),
        'relationship' => array(
         'base' => 'term', 
         'field' => 'tid', 
         'handler' => 'views_handler_relationship', 
         'label' => t('Example term'),
    ),
  );


  // Month ID field.
  $data['seasonality_chart']['month_id'] = array(
             'title' => t('Month id field'), 
            'help' => t('Month number'), 
        'field' => array(
          'handler' => 'views_handler_field_numeric',

          'click sortable' => TRUE,
        ), 
        'filter' => array(
          'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_numeric',
        ), 
        'sort' => array(
          'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
        ),
  );
    //---the concat field ---> here's where the trouble is <------
    // using $data['seasonality_chart']['months'] creates a non-existent field called seasonality_chart.months
    $data['']['months'] = array( //using no table does not return the field at all
    'title' => t('Months field'), 
        'help' => t('Month number list'),
    'field' => array(
        'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
        'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ),
    );

  return $data;
}

//this function comes from here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12359/add-a-group-by-in-views/12364#12364
function seasonality_chart_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  $query->add_groupby('tid');

  // hack to make the query constructor just ignore these fields (not adding them to the GROUP BY clause. It's needed to let it continue without problems
  $query->fields['seasonality_chart_month_id']['aggregate'] = TRUE;
  $query->fields['term_data_name']['aggregate'] = TRUE;
    $query->fields['term_data_vid']['aggregate'] = TRUE;
    $query->fields['months']['aggregate'] = TRUE;

    // ... do I need add_field() here instead? in addition?
    //$query->add_field('','GROUP_CONCAT(month_id) AS months');

  // Configure the fields that perform the aggregation (SUM, AVG, etc)
  $query->fields['months']['table'] = '';
  $query->fields['months']['field'] = "GROUP_CONCAT(month_id)";
  $query->fields['months']['alias'] = 'months';

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement a handler class for the field (most conveniently derived from [views_field_handler](http://views.doc.logrus.com/classviews__handler__field.html)). You also have to make the field handler known to Views; see the source code of [hook_views_data()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!views!docs!docs.php/function/hook_views_data/6) for an example.

Add the GROUP_CONCAT and GROUP BY clauses to the query in the field handler's [query()](http://views.doc.logrus.com/classviews__handler__field.html#4f661f91bcbe80d4a00c30a31456c502) method.

A tutorial style explanation of how to implement [hook_views_data()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!views!docs!docs.php/function/hook_views_data/6) and what other aspects you need to consider (like implementing [hook_views_handlers()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!views!docs!docs.php/function/hook_views_handlers/6)) is included in the views module, but you need the [Advanced help](http://drupal.org/project/advanced_help) module to have convenient access to it.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Oswald. I will give some of your suggestions a try. What I don't understand quite yet is why adding GROUP_CONCAT and GROUP BY in the field handler's query() is necessary instead of adding it in _views_query_alter, which is what I've done. All I need is for drupal not to prepend the tablename to the name of the field. Does that require an entire new field handler to accomplish? Perhaps so.  I'm updating my original post to include my code so far.

Comment: Thanks again for your help! I finally got it working, replacing all the group and concat information into the views_field_handler, as you suggested.